# How to draw Line charts in android

Tags: android, charts

Can anybody tell me how to draw a line chart in android with example. I searched for this for 2 days but I didn't get anywhere even in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/ ?

Comment: Is there something in specific you're having trouble with on this?  If it's something in your code, you could include that in your question as well.

Comment: [How I have drawn chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/7362757#7362757)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many charting libraries like [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/) and [flotgraph](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) are available have a look at that and make a try

Comment: follow this link @ammu this will have the working example http://achartengine.googlecode.com/files/achartengine-0.6.0-demo-source.zip

Comment: the plessure is mine go on with it @Ammu

Comment: hello  @Ammu as you know using  achart engine line we can draw line but i need custom line X and Y axis.